# log access denied events with Spring Security and J2EE container authentication

Tags: spring-security

I've got spring security configured as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = false)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .jee()
        .mappableRoles("ROLE1", "ROLE2");
    }
}
```

And then `@Secured` annotations with roles on the rest endpoints.

Doesn't matter what I do I don't seem to be able to create a custom handler for authorization (i.e. a user logged in successfully but doesn't have the right role to access a particular endpoint) error events.

What I tried was:

1. An exception handler with `@ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)` - doesn't get called. I understand that's by design, ok.
2. AuthenticationEntryPoint configured as 
   `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())`

   ```
   @Component( "restAuthenticationEntryPoint" )
   public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
       @Override
       public void commence( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                             AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException {
                             // logging
       }
   }
   ```

-doesn't get called

3. ApplicationListener - I can see it's getting called on context closed, so it's registered correctly but not called on authorization error.

All I need is a simple handler to log unsuccessful authorization events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It completely slipped my mind that the allowed roles are listed in web.xml as well for j2ee container authentication to work. So any user without a least one of those roles was just being rejected by the container.

Otherwise the first, simplest, method works fine. Hopefully my mistake will help someone in the future